# can not connect to EC2 instance running mongo db

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am running a mongo db server on one AWS EC2 instance. I can use mongo
command to access the database after I ssh to the instance.

However, when I try to use mongo command on another machine, it reports error that

{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }]
  originalError: { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' } }

I set the security group of the EC2 instance to open to all traffic from anywhere. No restrictions applied. There is no password or username set up on the mongo server process.

Why it refuses connection?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please double check the security group's incoming rules, and the network connectivity(SSH will do it).

Then, check Mongo db log for any stack trace:

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

It sounds to me like a mongo db server issue, mostly because of an unexpected shutting-down. Please refer to this article for more background info. and solution:
[Recover Data after an Unexpected Shutdown](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a network configuration issue. Verify that after you ssh to the remote machine, you can successfully ping the mongo server with the same ip.